# Vue 2 - Router value, this.$route, has wrong - empty value when component is created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In main App.vue component, I am displaying components based on this.$route path.

Template

`<topbar v-if="!isLoginPage" />`

Computed

```
  get isLoginPage() {
    return this.$route.path === "/login";
  }
```

The problem that I have is that App.vue component always gets initialized with empty value

[image]

So in login page, the topbar component is created and after a second, when router changes its value to correct path "/login", it gets destroyed.

How can I achieve result, where I will have correct value in v-if statement instantly when component is created on "/login route"?

Answer (score 2):

This does not work because `this.$route` is reactive and you have a conditional based on its value in the top level `App.vue` component. It is better to create a separate view component for the login page that renders the topbar component

**LoginView.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <topbar/>
  </div>
</template>
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

**router/index.js**

```js
const routes = [
  ...
  { path: '/login', component: '<path-to-login-view>' } 
]
```